# Does the bootstrap gem for rails contain a css reset?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Pretty much summarized in the title. Haven't been able to see anything about this subject.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen any evidence to support this possibility. I always include a reset.css file in my projects.

While we're on the subject of front end frameworks, I strongly recommend Semantic UI.

Comment: I dont think you need reset.css , you can always override style from your custom.css file and bootstrap will take care of the rest, I think thats what it is meant to be.